# What are the negative economic effects of lower taxes in the US?

Tags: united-states, economy, donald-trump, taxes

While lower taxes theoretically lets Americans keep more of their own money, what are the negative economic effects to this policy?

Comment: I think it is too broad. It heavily depends on what taxes are lowered and how much they are reduced. Quick negative effect - less money in some "budget" (I am not familiar with how money is collected is US).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A government that cuts taxes has less money. It, therefore, is unable to do as much, and so must cut some of its services (or borrow more). The government that cuts tax is unable to use that tax money to improve the economy.

For example, the government spends money on education. With less money from taxes, the government has to reduce spending on education. A less educated population is less productive, and that reduces GDP growth.

Alternatively, the government might choose to borrow money. Building up a debt that needs to be financed costs more money in the future.

Whether a tax cut ultimately improves the economy or not depends on how well the government would have spent the money if it had collected it in tax.

Comment: You might want to change the example: Education in the USA is a state matter, while the question seems to be triggered by the USA federal tax cuts. (I know it's just an example in the general case, so I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a number of details dealing with the specific tax cuts and how they are financed.

If the tax cuts are financed by cuts to public sector spending, their net economic effect might be less than if that spending was continued.  If the tax cut is financed by debt, that may cause inflation and higher costs for borrowing in the future.

If the original purpose of the tax is to account for negative externalities (tobacco taxes or carbon taxes for example), then cutting the taxes would allow those externalities to fall on the public.

There is also the possibility that a tax cut could just fail to accomplish its stated purpose if its not tailored well enough to its task.  For example, a tax cut aimed at increasing demand would have to be targeted towards the poor or specifically subsidize purchase of labor.  A tax cut aimed at increasing investment would be superfluous in an environment of cheap money where the stock market is already running hot and corporate cash reserves are very high.

Comment: I've done voted this answer due to the possible connotations of 'financed.'

Comment: @DrunkCynic Are you saying that taxes are revenue and therefore not a cost?  I've already listed two taxes that have primary functions which are not for raising revenue (there are even more such as tariffs).  Taxes are just a facet of government policy, anything that increases spending or decreases revenue can be assigned a monetary cost.

Comment: Yes. Taxes aren't a cost, a value that could be financed, though they should be considered as a budgetary line item. Sin taxes are designed to raise revenue, in order to offset costs, with a second order effect trying to effect action. Yes, there are taxes, even tax exemptions, that are built to drive social action.

Comment: @DrunkCynic That seems to be a word that could be fixed by an edit. What do you suggest instead of "how [tax cuts] are financed". I take that sentence to mean "how the government changes policy to cope with lower tax receipts".